# Coverity issue : Explicit Null dereferenced

Tags: c

I have the following section of code, which gives explicit null dereferenced.

```
uint64_t *var1 = NULL;

char *var2 = NULL;


//Alias transfer

var1 = (uint64_t *) var2;

//Dereferencing Null Pointer

*var1 = 0;
```

Can this be fixed if I reassign the *var1 to NULL again ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uint64_t *var1 = NULL;
char *var2 = NULL;
```

You have defined pointers var1 and var2 of type uint64_t and char respectively which are pointing to NULL .
And in this step

```
var1 = (uint64_t *) var2;
```

you are trying to make your var1 to point to the same location as that of var2 and casting it to uint64_t.So from the above two sections var1 and var2 are pointing to NULL pointer ie nothing in simple terms.

`*var1 = 0;`

in this line you are trying to assign a value 0 to a location pointed by var1 which is NUll location ie invalid address and de-referencing a invalid /Null address will result in crash.

Before assigning a value you need to allocate a memory and make the pointers to point to that memory location and then assign a value.

```
var1 = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));
*var1 = 0;
```

this should make your code to work.

Answer (score 3):

> Can this be fixed if I reassign the *var1 to NULL again

A pointer should be made to point to some valid memory location before writing something to it. In your case you are not doing it,so you have a segmentation fault(or crash) .
So before writing anything to some memory location memory has to allocated to the pointer.

```
uint64_t *var1 = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));
```

Comment: Thank you for the description (comments).It Cleared my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't understand that the `*` in a pointer declaration and the `*` in a pointer arithmetics expression mean completely opposite things.

`uint64_t *var1 = NULL;` this declares a `uint64_t` pointer (type `uint64_t*`)

`*var1 = 0;` this *dereferences* the pointer, i.e. accesses *memory stored at its address*. It does *not* give the pointer a new value. It modifies the pointed-to data. And in this case, there is no pointed-to data. `NULL` can't point to data. Hence the error.

If you want to change the value of your pointer, just do

`var1 = 0;`

I'm sorry if I have misunderstood the intent in your question. In that case, if you want to change the value of the pointed-to data, well, have the pointer point to some writeable memory first!

```
uint64_t var = 100;
/* ... */
var1 = &var; /* Get a pointer to the memory that is the variable var */
```

or

`uint64_t *var1 = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t)); /* Allocate memory for one uint64_t on the heap and set var1 to point at it */`